# Whats wrong with this code? .checked is probably the one i am not using correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple html form. its a trouble logging in page, two radio buttons, one for forgot password, and another for forgot username. When user click one of the radio buttons, a small form appears below the option and then he can proceed further. I have just written the username part. and have written a small function for it, but its not really working properly, in fact, its not working at all.

I have checked the jquery selector, the form #usernamedrop does hide, but the if statement is not working properly.

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
    $("#usernamedrop").hide();
    $("#usernameradio").change(function(e){
        if($("#usernameradio").checked){
            $("#usernamedrop").show();
        }else {
            $("#usernamedrop").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

The html is the following:

```
<body>
<div id="logindiv">
<h1>What is the problem?</h1>
    <div>
        <div class="formentry">
            <input type="radio" name="troublekind" id="usernameradio" value="username">
            <label for="usernameradio">I forgot my username</label>
        </div>
        <div class="formentry">
            <input type="radio" name="troublekind" id="passwordradio" value="password">
            <label for="passwordradio">I forgot my password</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <form id="usernamedrop">
        <h2>Please Enter</h2>
        <div class="formentry">
            <label for="dateofbirth">Date Of Birth</label><input type="date" name="dateofbirth" id="dateofbirth">
        </div>
        <div class="formentry">
             <label for="placeofbirth">Place Of Birth</label><input type="text" name="placeofbirth" id="placeofbirth">
        </div>
        <input type="submit" name="submitusernamedrop" value="Submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks All, not just correcting code. Really learnt something about Objects and DOM selections here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing Vanialla JS and jQuery. `$("#usernameradio")` is a jQuery object and it doesn't have `checked` property.

You can get checked property using multiple ways:

1. `this.checked;`, Simple and best way
2. `$(this).is(':checked');`
3. `$(this).prop('checked');`

Use

```
$("#usernameradio").change(function(e){
    if(this.checked){
        $("#usernamedrop").show();
    }else {
        $("#usernamedrop").hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$("#usernameradio").change(function(e){
     if($(this).prop('checked')){
         $("#usernamedrop").show();
     }else {
         $("#usernamedrop").hide();
     }
 });
```

I use .prop to check if property has value or not `prop('checked')` returns true if the radio is checked.

Answer (score 0):

The property `checked` is on the DOM element, not the jQuery collection. `this` refers to the element, so you can do `this.checked` or `$(this).prop('checked')`. Finally, you can also use `toggle`, which takes a "switch" to hide or show the element:

```
$("#usernameradio").change(function(){
    $("#usernamedrop").toggle(!this.checked);
});
```